# Multiple Marker InfoWindow in Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I've testing this for about 1 hour now. But for some reason I can't make it work, to display another infowindow text for each marker.
Clicking each of them, will open a new infowindow (the old one will be closed *which is good*), but the text inside the window is always the text I set in the last marker:

```js
function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.133333,10.416667);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var markers = [];

    for (var i = 0, dataPhoto; dataPhoto = data.photos[i]; i++) {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
                   dataPhoto.longitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        title: dataPhoto.infotitle,
        map: map,
      });

      /* Create Info Windows */         

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: " "
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<h3>'+marker.title+'</h3>'+' Infotext');
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
}
```

I've been seeing some solutions around here, but none of them seemed to work properly for me.
I'd really appreciate your help!

See [online demo](http://darkskyz.de/maps/).

Answer (score 3):

You simply have to set the Content to this.title, instead of marker.title

```js
infowindow.setContent('<h3>'+this.title+'</h3>'+' Infotext');
```

Thanks
dz46

Answer (score 0):

you dont have any way to store the infoWindow.. Look at my code, i use infoBubble library but it should be very similar. This is probably more code than you need, but more the merrier..

```js
/**
 * infoBubble Variable
 * This variable is globally defined for defaults that are loaded.
 */
var infoBubbles = [];
/**
 * array of all of the markers that are on the map
 * 
 * @type {Array}
 * @author Mike DeVita
 * @copyright 2011 MapIT USA
 * @category map_Js
 */
var markersArray = [];
/**
 * array of all of the sidebar items for all of the markers on the map
 * 
 * @type {Array}
 * @author Mike DeVita
 * @copyright 2011 MapIT USA
 * @category map_Js
 */
var sidebarHtmlArray = [];

/**
 * setPoints(locations)
 * 
 * sets the marker, infoBubble and sidebarItem based on the locations 
 * that were returned from the JSON query.
 * 
 * @param {array} locations array of all of the points, and their settings/html
 * 
 * @author Mike DeVita
 * @author Google Maps API
 * @copyright 2011 MapIT USA
 * @category map_js
 */     
function setPoints(locations){      
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        /** @type {array} reassigns locations array to be point, isolates it to the setPoints() function */
        var point = locations;
        /** @type {google} generates Googles API form of the lat lng passed from var point */
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(point[i].lat, point[i].lng);

        /**
         * marker variable, stores all of the information pertaining to a specific marker
         * this variable creates the marker, places it on the map and then also sets some
         * custom options for the infoBubbles.
         * 
         * @type {google}
         */
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: point[i].marker_icon
        });

        /** push the marker to the markersArray to delete or show the overlays */
        markersArray.push(marker);

        var sidebarItem = point[i].sidebarHtmlView;
        sidebarHtmlArray.push(sidebarItem);
        infoBubbles[i] = new InfoBubble({ 
            map: map, 
            minHeight: point[i].min_height,
            maxHeight: point[i].max_height,
            minWidth: point[i].min_width,
            maxWidth: point[i].max_width,
            disableAutoPan: false, 
            hideCloseButton: false, 
            arrowPosition: 30, 
            padding:12
        }); 
        var tabs = point[i].tabs;
        infoBubbles[i].addTab('Company', point[i].html);
        for (var ii = 0; ii < tabs.length; ii++) {
            infoBubbles[i].addTab(tabs[ii].tabTitle, tabs[ii].tabContent);
        }
        /**
         * add the listeners for the markerClicks and the sideBarClicks 
         * 
         * @type {google}
         * @todo eventDomListener does not work yet, this is the click listener of the sidebar item's
         */
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', handleMarkerClick(marker, i)); 
    }   
}


function handleMarkerClick(marker,index) { 
    return function() { 
        if (!infoBubbles[index].isOpen()) { 
            infoBubbles[index].open(map, marker); 
        }else{
            infoBubbles[index].close(map, marker); 
        }
    } 
}

/**
 * addmarker(location)
 * 
 * adds the marker to the map and pushes the marker
 * to the end of the markersArray
 * 
 * @param {google} location LatLng of where the marker should be put
 * 
 * @author Mike DeVita
 * @author Google API
 * @copyright 2011 MapIT USA
 * @category map_js
 */
function addMarker(location, marker_icon){
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: marker_icon
    });
    markersArray.push(marker);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
var markers = new Array();
var infowindow = new Array();
var map;
function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.133333,10.416667);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    for (var i = 0, dataPhoto; dataPhoto = data.photos[i]; i++) {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
                   dataPhoto.longitude);
     markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        title: dataPhoto.infotitle,
        map: map,
      });
      /* Create Info Windows */         

      infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: " "
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
        infowindow[i].setContent('<h3>'+this.title+'</h3>'+' Infotext');
        infowindow[i].open(map, this);
      });

    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
}
```